# Server-generated S3 policy with Fine Uploader

Tags: file-upload, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

The [Amazon S3 integration docs](http://docs.fineuploader.com/endpoint_handlers/amazon-s3.html) for Fine Uploader instruct users to create an AJAX handler to sign an S3 upload policy generated by the client after performing server-side verification.

In my application, it would make more sense to construct the policy on the server, sign it, and return the entire package to the client to present to S3 for the upload. Is there any way to configure Fine Uploader to pull a server-generated policy instead of asking the server to validate and sign a client-generated one?

Comment: Are you aware that policies are only used for multipart-encoded POST (non-chunked) uploads to S3?  If chunking is enabled, we make use of the REST API, which does not involve policies.

Comment: @RayNicholus I found [the blog post](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/08/16/fine-uploader-s3-upload-directly-to-amazon-s3-from-your-browser/#server-side-integration) describing the workflow for the chunked upload, but the [S3 walkthrough docs linked from the home page[(http://docs.fineuploader.com/endpoint_handlers/amazon-s3.html) still discuss only the POST uploads with required policies.

Comment: The docs page discusses both chunked and non-chunked uploads is detail.  Have a look at the "Chunked Uploads" section.

Comment: @RayNicholus The "Chunked Uploads" section does not explain that the earlier "Required server-side task" is not applicable in that case. To verify the correctness of a signature request for a chunked upload, is it necessary to parse the `headers` attribute as an HTTP request and inspect that?

Comment: That is correct.  Please have a look at the various server-side examples linked to on that doc page for examples of this logic.

Comment: @RayNicholus The Python examples are dead links, the Java example (the one I'd already looked at) does no validation, and the PHP and Node examples just check whether the bucket name is present anywhere.

Comment: I assume you are talking about the blog post.  I was referring to the docs page, where the links are all correct.  I'll fix the links in the blog now.  All examples are here: https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server.  The examples are meant to be starting points, not drop-ins for all existing web applications.  You can modify the existing examples to suit your situation.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your initial question, it is possible to override some elements of the generated policy, but there are some items, such as the key, that you cannot change via the policy document.  This is discussed more in [Github issue #1120](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1120).

If you want to override portions of the policy document, you'll have to disable chunking (since policy documents aren't part of chunked uploads, as described in the comments).  Your best bet is to simply validate the policy/header strings.  It's pretty easy to do this, and what elements you validate depending entirely on your application requirements.